# Does the Lego Mindstorms EV3 software work on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, ev3-g, mac

Will there be issues with the software, or will it work properly on macOS High Sierra?

My Mac: Retina MacBook Pro 13", Early 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded to High Sierra already. I just tried loading a large/complex program in the educational version of the EV3 software and sending it to the EV3 with both Bluetooth and USB. So, it looks like there are at least not any major issues.